# How to add Dark mode toggle in Tailwind CSS using CDN

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css, darkmode, tailwind-ui

I am novice in Javascript. Recently I started using Tailwind Css. Now I want to add it in my blogger template. But I don't know how to add a dark mode toggle button in Tailwind Css. How Can I add a toggle Dark mode toggle button in Tailwind Css.

N.B. As I'm using blogger platform, so There's no way to add it from local library. So I use CDN.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.15/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Do I need any other CDN ? Or Javascript code ?

Comment: I'd suggest to use Flowbite with Tailwind, as it has a option for a [dark mode switcher](https://flowbite.com/docs/customize/dark-mode/#dark-mode-switcher)

Comment: @ArjunJakkipally They said to add  'config js dark mode', but O want to use just CDN. Not extra Things. And I even don't know how to use config.js... 

Comment: No if you scroll down to Dark mode switcher, you don't need config.js

Answer (score 2):

Can you please check the below code link? Hope it will work for you. We have used Tailwind’s library which is flowbite And it provides a dark-mode toggle switch inbuild so we can apply this.

Please refer to this link: https://codesandbox.io/embed/fervent-fast-6v9fn5?autoresize=1&fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

you can also follow this document: https://flowbite.com/docs/customize/dark-mode/

Comment: I'm satisfied in your such approach. Thanks. And I Upvoted your answer as well as.